# Bazel - ERROR: missing input file '//server:files/src/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bazel

I want to compile some Typescript files and create a Node.js Image from the compiled Javascript files. It works fine when I have only **one** Typescript file with this `BUILD` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "compile",
    srcs = ["src/index.ts"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "files",
    srcs = ["compile"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    entry_point = "files",
)
```

But as soon as I introduce **multiple** Typescript files like this:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "compile",
    srcs = ["src/index.ts", "src/util.ts"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "files",
    srcs = ["compile"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = ["files"],
    entry_point = "files/src/index.js",
)
```

Bazel doesn't find the entrypoint file:

```
ERROR: missing input file '//server:files/src/index.js'
ERROR: /home/flo/Desktop/my-own-minimal-bazel/server/BUILD:15:1: //server:server: missing input file '//server:files/src/index.js'
Target //server:server failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/flo/Desktop/my-own-minimal-bazel/server/BUILD:15:1 1 input file(s) do not exist
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only get the repo to build if I break up the ts_library into two seperate ts_libs, one for the library, and one for the index.ts:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = [
        "util.ts",
    ],
)

ts_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [
        "index.ts",
    ],
    deps = [":lib"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "libfiles",
    srcs = ["lib"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

filegroup(
    name = "mainfile",
    srcs = ["main"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = [
        ":libfiles",
        ":mainfile",
    ],
    entry_point = ":mainfile",
)
```

The above code is in a pull request to your repo. I'm not sure why you are unable to reference a single file of the filegroup!

Comment: that works, but the `dist` folder isn't build by Bazel. I would need to run `tsc --build` manually. Is it possible to build the Typescript files with Bazel into the `dist` folder?

Comment: ohhh I see, I assumed that bazel was building that folder for you based off the tsconfig. Trying again.

Comment: I forgot to put the `dist` folder into my `.gitignore`. My fault

Comment: It works  Do you know, why it has this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

(Blind fix, I cannot try it now.)

I believe you need to use `entry_point = "src/index.js",` because `files` is just the name of the filegroup, it's not part of the paths.

Either that, or `entry_point = "server/src/index.js",` in case `nodejs_image` expects a package-root-relative path.

Comment: `entry_point = "src/index.js"` produces: `ERROR: missing input file '//server:src/index.js'` and `entry_point = "server/src/index.js"` outputs `ERROR: missing input file '//server:server/src/index.js'`

Comment: If you want to try it, you can checkout this repo: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Comment: No, i have not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this with the `$(location LABEL)` make variable pointed at the output file by name, `src/index.js`:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "compile",
    srcs = ["src/index.ts", "src/util.ts"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "files",
    srcs = ["compile"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = ["files"],
    entry_point = "$(location src/index.js)",
)
```

Note the `entry_point` is set to `"$(location src/index.js)"` - this locates the output file by relative path, relative to the BUILD file, that the `files` filegroup has collected.

Comment: When I use the code from your answer, I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'example/server/$(location src/index.js)'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

Comment: Are you sure you've only modified the `entry_point` line?  I just sent a PR https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo/pull/2, that branch builds for me locally with `bazel build //...`

Comment: Yeah, it builds. But it doesn't run